# Page.FindControl() returns null when searching for dynamic control

Tags: asp.net, webforms, radio-button

In asp.net web form-I have added group of  radio button dynamically in web form and on clicking submit button when i try to the find the
 radio button button with its id using find.control(id), it returns null. Can some body help me am new to asp.net?

```
RadioButton myControl1 = (RadioButton)Page.FindControl("r11");
```

Answer (score 4):

Two reasons.

When you add controls dynamically, you must re-add them when the page posts back (In Page_Init is a good place). See [How to persist a dynamic control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567707/how-to-persist-a-dynamic-control-c)

The other is that Page.FindControl() only goes one level down, you need to recursively search down the list. See [Better way to find control in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955769/better-way-to-find-control-in-asp-net)

Comment: In oder to re add them how do i know which checked boxes are checked?.My question is, dynamically added radio button is checked and on submit i couldn't find the control to get its check property.