# C#/ASP.net - How to dynamically fill table with checkboxes in each cell and read those checkbox values

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, asp-classic

I am dynamically generating a table (depending on user selection from a dropdown list) with checkboxes in each cell. The user will check a few (more than 1) checkboxes and hit the start button which will send out emails with information on checkboxes selected in the dynamic table.

Currently I am not able to get the table when the button is clicked to see which checkboxes have been selected. Below is code I am using to get the dynamically generated resultsTable, but it always comes out as null.

```
protected void btnRequestChips_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            login();
            string debug_output = "";
            Table chipsTable = (Table)Page.FindControl("resultsTable");
            foreach (TableRow row in chipsTable.Rows)
            {
                foreach (Table cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    foreach (Control ctrl in cell.Controls)
                    {
                        //CONTROL IS TEXBOXT: EXTRACT VALUES//
                        if (ctrl is CheckBox)
                        {
                            CheckBox chkBOx = (CheckBox)ctrl;
                            if (chkBOx.Checked)
                            {
                                debug_output += chkBOx.ID + Environment.NewLine;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Below is what the aspx file looks like:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentBody" runat="server">
    <div class="controlContainer">
        <asp:Table id="resultsTable" BorderWidth="1" GridLines="Both" runat="server" title="Device Support"/>      
        <br />
    </div>      
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21663763/page-findcontrol-returns-null-when-searching-for-dynamic-control

Comment: You will have to first get the container handle which hosts your dynamic control and then call this method.

Comment: Is it html <table> or DataTable of c#?

Comment: It is an html table.

Comment: nonexistentmyth- should I be looking for content4 first. How would I go about that?

Comment: @user1650464 - Try this
    ContentPlaceHolder cp = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("ContentBody");
    Table tbl = (Table)cp.FindControl("resultsTable");